# Extracting layers from Paint.NET

Tags: images, paint.net

Is there a way to automatically save layers as separate image files from a Paint.NET (`pdn`) file?

For example, if I have 5 layers in a `pdn` file, I would like to save them as 5 separate `.png` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paint.NET doesn't seem to be able to do this natively. Take a look at the utilities on this page:
http://www.comsquare.ch/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=36&Itemid=55

Specifically, `pdn2png` can save each layer into a separate file with the `/split` option, like so:

```
pdn2png /split yourfile.pdn
```

Alternatively, for something with a graphical interface, try this:
http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?showtopic=9704

I did a quick test with a 2-layer PDN file, and both seem to work as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly Layer Saver from this link http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?showtopic=9704 does NOT work with Paint.Net 4.0 and above.. 
But pdn2png from http://comsquare.dynvpn.de/forums/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=64&sid=871b9b812347c2a654cf00cb1e02352c works well!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit laborious but it works:

1. Uncheck all but the first layer.
2. Save as .png file in a convenient folder.
3. Undo the "flatten image" to restore all layers.
4. Uncheck all but the next layer and repeat steps 2 & 3.
5. Repeat for all layers.

You will now have all individual layers saved as .png files which can be re-imported into a new Paint.net image as required.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another plugin which adds a file type, a zip file containing all the layers and some additional data.

https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/31597-alternative-to-layersaver/

To use it, extract the the provided zip and copy the dll into FileTypes folder in Paint.Net's installation directory (don't forget to restart Paint.Net). Then you can save as your .pdn files as a .zip file (choose "ZIP - Compressed Archive of Layers" for "Save as type" in the "Save As" dialog). The saved zip file will contain all the layers.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tested this solution. It is not a random Google hit. This was the best thing I could find and I was very happy with it. I will add a few words anyway.